# Problems with using syntax similar to XML's "CDATA" in my own parser?

Tags: xml, parsing

I'm modifying a CMS with ##token## support.  One of the requests that has come in is to allow conditional output based on the presence of data in the ##token##.  I'm thinking of structuring it like:

```
<![my_token[<div class="mymarkup">##my_token##</div>]]>
```

Which is basically 100% ripping off XML's CDATA syntax.  The advantage I'm seeing with it is that's a known construct (and I might be able to get library help for finding these tokens), the disadvantages are ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably stick with a custom attribute on the `div` - it would require less parsing work on your part and wouldn't break compatibility with other parsers out there.  For example,

```
<div class="mymarkup" tokenize="true">##mytoken##</div>
```

It would be far easier to adapt XML/HTML validation and parsing software to that than to try to adapt a `CDATA`-like syntax.  The reason `CDATA` is the way it is is to specify that what's inside it is character data the parser should ignore, rather than that it's interesting data to be parsed in a special way.

Comment: That actually introduces an element of analysis we're not currently doing.  Right now token replacement is a dumb string replace on the (user-supplied) markup.  How could I reconcile these?  There's additional headaches of showing more than just the token inside a div, is your suggestion that the entire div is pass/fail?

Comment: The idea is the attribute `tokenize` specifies that the content of this element contains data to be tokenized.  It would help your string replacement avoid accidentally replacing something inside a tag.